# Django social auth how to get permission or die trying

Tags: python-social-auth, django-socialauth

In my app, I need an email for every user. Facebook inconveniently for me does not provide it as a part of public profile. So I ask for permission:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'public_profile']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email', 
}
```

Now, user has the option to not grant the email permission. I want to make registration impossible without granting this permission. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [add function](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline) to the [authentication pipeline](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline) that enforces the email requirement or raises [`AuthForbidden`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/exceptions.py#L102) instead. Here's an example:

```
from social_core.exceptions import AuthForbidden


def email_required(backend, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if details.get('email') or user and user.email:
        return
    else:
        raise AuthForbidden(backend)
```

You need to put that function before the user or social relation is created, so after `social_uid` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out myself after all, however I forgot to check if I already have email. You spared me a future headache.

To anyone reading this later, one problem I encountered was that any exception in the pipeline results in a `ValueError`, so catch that and not particular exceptions. This will hopefully save you some time.